# How to execute a command inside a screen session

Tags: linux, enter, gnu-screen

I would like to know how to execute a command inside a screen session.
i searched and I found this :

```
screen -S nameofscreen -X stuff "command"
```

When I type this, the command is typed inside the screen but it is not executed.
So my queston is how to press enter using this command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `bash` shell you can use `ctrl-V` to explicitly put non-printable characters into a string.  So try `ctrl-V` `ctrl-L` `ctrl-V` `ctrl-M` at the end of your command just before the `"`.

Comment: For me, it is `CTRL+V` + `ENTER` to generate `^M`, thus `screen -S test -X stuff 'top^M'` as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/201826/383800).

Answer (score 5):

I'd do something like this:

```
screen -S sessionName bash -c 'cmd; exec bash'
```

it starts a new session executes `cmd` and launches shell (otherwise it'd drop that new session).

`-X` will allow you to send input to a specified session -- that's why your command didn't execute. To execute it you'd need to add *enter* sign like Paul suggested. It can be done with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. That will produce that `^M`. So:

```
screen -S sessionName -X stuff 'cmd^M'
```

That, in itself, won't however attach a detached session.

Answer (score 4):

In bash, you can use `\n` in the `$'...'` construct:

```
screen -S nameofscreen -X stuff $'command\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time, but what I found is:
Version of **screen 4.06** has a bug.
If you want to send a command over a shared screen session like this, it fails:

```
screen -S shared_session_name -X stuff "command \n"
```

Screen fails with an error:

```
Cannot opendir /run/screen/S-$USER: Permissions denied
```

After update to the version **screen 4.09** it works.