# passing the command with an enter in existing screen session using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, enter, gnu-screen

I am writing a bash script.
Below is my command

```
screen -x stack -p n-api -X stuff "ls"
```

This command just pastes this command never executes. 
Hence i used

```
control + V + enter command
```

to form a symbol

```
^M
```

which is essentially an enter. but whenever i open the script to edit some other pieces the command goes away and again i am not able to press enter in the screen session using bash script

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13953/sending-text-input-to-a-detached-screen), this seems to work for me:

```
screen -x stack -p n-api -X stuff "ls$(printf \\r)"
```

Other solutions that can be found in [How to execute a command inside a screen session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406823) are

```
screen -x stack -p n-api -X stuff 'ls\n'
```

as well as your solution by inserting `^M` with `ctrl-V` `ctrl-L` `ctrl-V` `ctrl-M`